# Jmeter JSR223 Unable to read data from CSV file

Tags: performance, groovy, jmeter

Requirement is ItemID should be read from external CSV file and passed in the JSR223 preprocessor script. This is the groovy code in JSR223 and it is working as expected in the grrovy executer.

```
def items = []
    List<String> lines = new File("C:\\Users\\854986\\itemid.csv").readLines()
    def itemNo = RandomUtils.nextInt(5, 10) 

    1.upto(itemNo) { index ->
        def item = [:]
        def lineFromCsv = lines.get(index as int)
        item.put('itemId', lineFromCsv)
```

But it jmeter it is throwing error and below is the error message.
"2022-11-15 12:34:14,398 ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor 3
javax.script.ScriptException: org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlException$Parsing: JsonBuilder@1:20 parsing error near '... ment, miss ...'
at org.apache.commons.jexl2.scripting.JexlScriptEngine.compile(JexlScriptEngine.java:237)"./
I have java 19.0.1, Jmeter 5.4.3 and groovy 4.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about "groovy code". Any reason to use `jexl2` language in the JSR223 PreProcessor?

Make sure to choose `groovy` as the language and at least this error should go away. Groovy is the [recommended scripting option since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) mainly because [Groovy provides maximum performance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter) comparing to other engines

[image]